# send cookies when leaving page in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I want to remove the Cookies, in case of the Logged-In User leaves the Website by closing the tab/browser without logging-Out. My Problem is, even if I refresh the page with F5 or click the 'Reset'-button, it runs the logout function and sent me to the Login-Page. Any ideas?

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {

        logout();

})


function logout(){

var sessionArr = getSessionArr();


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/logout.php",
    data: "sessionArray=" + sessionArr,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg, string, jpXHR) {
        alert("cookies sent");
    }
});
Cookies.remove('user', { expires:null, path: '' }); // removed!
window.location.href = "http://localhost/CookieSite/login.html";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There is no solution for this problem. You can't detect if a window is closed.